# How do I add groups to Empathy's contact list?

Tags: 11.04, empathy

I'm wondering how I can add new group to Empathy's contact list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select any contact.
2. Right-click on it.
3. Choose Edit.
4. You'll be presented by a window in which you can add groups (and not only for that particular user).

<sub>For reference see "3. Add New Group" in http://digitizor.com/2009/09/21/5-tips-to-help-you-get-started-with-empathy/</sub>

Comment: why did not I think to do so?