# How do I manage groups in Empathy in recent releases?

Tags: 15.10, empathy, contacts

I want to manage some Google (google talk, hangouts, whatever) contacts in groups, like I used to. Specifically I want to move some contacts from *Ungrouped* to existing groups.

Unfortunately, I can't use Edit (like [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57588/how-do-i-add-groups-to-empathys-contact-list) because this option is not available to me (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

How can I manage groups in empathy now? I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Right click on the contact

Comment: That's how I got the screenshot for the question.

Comment: Seems to be working for me hu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here, in case someone else stumbles into the same problem. As it turns out, Contacts were disabled in Online Accounts, but it took me a while to figure it out because Empathy **must be closed when you change this configuration**. Empathy apparently doesn't notice *on the fly* that you changed the online accounts. What I did to solve this was:

1. Close empathy.
2. Turn on Contacts in Online Accounts.
3. Open Empathy.

Only then I was able to use the *Edit* option in the contact menu.